# How to Inject all subclasses of a specific class with no common interface?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dozer

### Question:

In order to `Inject` all subclasses of a superclass with no common interface, I created an interface tightly-coupled to said superclass, that every "properly" written subclass is supposed to implement. 
**This works, but seems insane. Was there a better way?**

A simple cast do not work, as the `Instance` holds only a proxy that do not resolves to any real subclass of the interface when called. This results in a `ClassCastException`.

### Some context:

I was recently tasked to provide framework code for an application. In this application, several data transfer objects are mapping from and to service level POJOs, but their mappings are not always trivial. Dozer is used to do most of the work and to avoid boilerplate code.

In the specific cases requiring explicit mapping instructions, the current recommendation with Dozer is to use the API driven mapping. All the `BeanMappingBuilder` subclasses, defining the mappings, should be added to the Dozer mapper upon initialisation.

In order to keep all the work needed to add a new `BeanMappingBuilder` in one place, I came with a convoluted use of dependancy injection that will automatically add it to the Dozer mapper, despite it having no common interface, only a common superclass with the others.

### Some code:

**The interface:**

```
@Local
public interface DtoBeanMappingBuilder {

    BeanMappingBuilder get();

}
```

**Subclass example:**

```
@Stateless
public class SomeDtoMappingBuilder extends BeanMappingBuilder implements DtoBeanMappingBuilder {

    @Override
    public BeanMappingBuilder get() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        mapping(
            // Some mapping...
        );
    }

}
```

**Mapper with injection point:**

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class DtoBeanMapper {

    private DozerBeanMapper innerMapper;

    @Inject
    @Any
    private Instance<DtoBeanMappingBuilder> mappingBuilders;

    public <D> D map(Object source, Class<D> destinationClass) {
        return innerMapper.map(source, destinationClass);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        innerMapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
        mappingBuilders.forEach(mb -> innerMapper.addMapping(mb.get()));
    }
}
```